# reindent shortcut in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indenting code in Sublime text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2)

I'm trying to learn keyboard shortcuts in Sublime. What is the keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text 2 for reindent? According to some pages it should be <kbd>TAB</kbd> but that only indents, not reindents.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can find it in `Edit>>Line>>Reindent`, but it does not have a shortcut by default. You can add a shortcut by going to the menu Preferences - Keybindings-User, then add there (the config file takes as a JSON format):

```
[
    { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent"} 
]
```

(example of using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key for that functionality)

Comment: You can also add `"args": {"single_line": false}` to reindent the whole text

Comment: `[
  { "keys": ["super+shift+l"], "command": "reindent"} 
]`
like atom

Comment: @Ayonix please provide full syntax. And also if I want to add two bindings for whole text and for selected text, how I will do. Please share full syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PlanetHackers 
`[
    { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}},
 { "keys": ["f11"], "command": "reindent"} 
]`
should do

Comment: Xcode style: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "reindent"}` ;-)

Comment: For Mac, I use this: `{"keys": ["super+\\"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}`

Answer (score 6):

I use `cmd-[` and `cmd-]` for indenting but I am not sure exactly what you mean by "reindent"...

Ahh, OK I get your question now, you can use the command to re-calculate and apply correct indentation to a file. For example, if you open a file that has had been programmatically altered and had whitespace stripped or tabs removed you would use the reindent command to restore correct formatting.

Comment: there is a menu item edit-->line-->reindent

Comment: Why is edit->line->reindent grayed out for me?

Comment: Its grayed out because you have to select a line first